# How to populate select options with unique data and return a value as selected item?

Tags: javascript, knockout.js, knockout-2.0

I have a data object passed to an `observableArray` that looks like this:

```
self.Players = ko.observableArray([{

    "LastName": "Jordan",
        "FirstName": "Michael",
        "Team": "Chicago Bulls",
        "Jersey": "23"
}, {
    "LastName": "Duncan",
        "FirstName": "Tim",
        "Team": "San-Antonio Spurs",
        "Jersey": "21"
}, {
    "LastName": "Duncan",
        "FirstName": "Tim",
        "Team": "San-Antonio Spurs",
        "Jersey": "21"
}, {
    "LastName": "Jordan",
        "FirstName": "Michael",
        "Team": "Chicago Bulls",
        "Jersey": "23"
}
    ]);
```

I need to populate a `Select Options` with the *unique* First and Last Name of each player while also passing the Jersey value as Selected value. The data can have duplicates.

So each time a player is selected, I need the Jersey number passed to:

```
self.SelectedPlayer = ko.observable('');
```

I attempted to do something like this:

```
self.UniquePlayers = ko.computed(function () {
       var uniquePlayers = ko.utils.arrayMap(self.Players(),

           function (data) {
               return data.FirstName + ' ' + data.LastName
           });

       return ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues(uniquePlayers).sort();
   });
```

This works, except I do not get the Jersey as it is not returned.

I also tried returning the data object:

```
           function (data) {
               return data
           });
```

This allows me to specify the `optionsValue` and `optionsText`.

```
  <select class="form-control" 
  data-bind="options: UniquePlayers,
             optionsText: function(item){return item.FirstName + ' ' + item.LastName},
             optionsValue: 'Jersey',
  value: SelectedPlayer"></select>
```

But I do not get unique values and I am not able to access the `optionsValue`:

```
self.SelectedPlayer().Jersey;
```

How so I display the unique player first and last name and also get the jersey as optionsValue?

Comment: Regarding the "tags in question titles" issue, please see this post on meta: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/19190/should-questions-include-tags-in-their-titles

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can't use `ko.utils.arrayGetDistinctValues()` for an array that contains objects. This function works on primitive values only, objects on the other hand can have identical properties without being identical themselves.

Use something like this:

```
self.UniquePlayers = ko.computed(function () {
    var uniquePlayers = [], index = {};

    ko.utils.arrayForEach(self.Players(), function (p) {
        var fullName = p.FirstName + ' ' + p.LastName;
        if ( !(fullName in index) ) {
            uniquePlayers.push({text: fullName, player: p});
            index[fullName] = true;
        }
    });

    return uniquePlayers.sort();
});
```

and

```
<select class="form-control" data-bind="
    options: UniquePlayers,
    optionsText: 'fullName',
    optionsValue: 'player',
    value: SelectedPlayer
"></select>
```

Of course it would be sensible to precalculate the `fullName` values once and store then in the player objects during viewmodel init.

Comment: Thanks my friend, as always!

Answer (score 0):

Writing anonymous functions in viewmodel isn't the best idea, also I think you complicated your code too much, I don't think you really need `ko.computed` in this case, anyway, why don't you go for something like:

```
function (data) {
    var obj = data;
    obj.fullName = data.FirstName + ' ' + data.LastName;
    return obj;
});
```

If you would create a jsfiddle demo it would easier to play with.